# C: Sending and Receiving a file over a socket

Tags: c, file, sockets, network-programming

I am trying to implement a distributed p2p file sharing system where a peer can both send and download files from other peers. But, I am having some trouble downloading and saving the file to a directory.

Here is where I send the requested file

```
while(!feof(requestedfile)) {
    bytes_read = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), requestedfile);
    send(clientSock, buf, bytes_read, 0);

}
```

When I try to download, I do the following

```
while(recv(clientSock, currentLinePointer, 1, 0) != 0) {
    currentLinePointer++;
}
```

I am new to C, but I know I have 2 issues

1. How do I perform a more efficient read? If I read 1024 bytes at a time, at the last block of data, there only may be half of the 1024 bytes filled. Will the other 512 nonsense bytes cause errors in my file? (I know bad things happen to pictures when you try to read and save a jpg with nonsense bytes at the end)
2. Now that I have read the file, how do I save that file? Say a peer request "hello.jpg". The setup I have can send and read that file, but now how can I save that file to the requesting peers directory "PATH/Pictures/"

Comment: Remember that `recv` returns the number of bytes actually received, -1 on error and zero on connection closed. It might help making the socket non-blocking.

Comment: As for saving to the "correct" folder, either modify the protocol so the sending program send the path first, or have it set in the receiving program.

Comment: It would be more efficient to use sendfile(2) at both ends (http://linux.die.net/man/2/sendfile)

Comment: @MartinBroadhurst _If_ this is a system which have `sendfile` (it also exists on BSD I think (and therefore OSX)). It's not on Windows, but Windows might have other similar functionality.

Comment: Please don't mix camelCase `clientSock` with old C-style `bytes_read` and no-time-for-formatting `requestedfile`.

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740121(v=vs.85).aspx

> If no error occurs, recv returns the number of bytes received

You need to know what the return value of recv is and only write that number of bytes to your file.

Comment: ok, but once I read in all the bytes from this file, how do I then save that file?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read 4096 bytes at once since this is the standard size of a disk sector nowadays (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_sector):

```
char* buffer = (char*)malloc(4096), *position = buffer;

while((bytes_read = recv(clientSock, position, 4096, 0) > 0)
{
    if(fwrite(position, 1, bytes_read, localFile) != bytes_read)
    {
        // do some error handling here
        break;
    }
    position += 4096;
}

// and here

free(buffer);
```

Comment: You can always check the block size by calling ''stat()'' on the file and then checking the ''st_blksize'' field of the ''struct stat''.

Answer (score 0):

`recv()` returns the number of bytes received, 0 if connection is closed and -1 on error. That basically answers your question.

You should also keep track of the value returned by `send()`. It returns the number of bytes sent, or at last put in buffer for sending. **It will not always send everything you tell it to** if the buffer is full or the connection is lost. Keep track of its return value to control the send buffer usage and avoid gaps in the file being transfered. You may have to perform a new `send()` call to send the part of the data it refused to in a previous call.